# Retrieving json and put to textboxes

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I have a json data from database and I want to put them inside textboxes separately. Here's my code below.

***HTML***

```
<input type="text" class="form- " name="certificate[]" id="certificate" style="width:300px">
```

I have only one textbox and i want to loop it base on how many count of data inside the json.

***Jquery***

```
var objJSON = JSON.parse(response['data'][0].certificate);
$.each(objJSON, function (i, v) {
     $('#certificate').val(v.med_sbj_list); 
});
```

I PARSE the data because it is a JSON string. And I `console.log` the json and here's the output

[image]

[edited]

Comment: *"I have a json data from database and I want to put them inside textboxes separately."* - Your HTML shows only one textbox, which you continuously overwrite the value of with each iteration.

Comment: @TylerRoper yes sir i know sir. But i want to loop also the textbox base on the number of the json.

Comment: Please include the HTML context, including multiple textboxes, so we have a better idea of how it's laid out.

Comment: @TylerRoper okay sir. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a string having those inputs and then append where ever you want

1. 1-Create a variable that will contain empty string
2. Loop through the json objects and append it to variable by creating input tag
3. add that tag to html

**For example**

**HTML**

```
<div id="input_container"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
var objJSON = JSON.parse(response['data'][0].certificate);
var inputs = "";
$.each(objJSON, function (i, v) {
    inputs += '<input type="text" class="form- " name="certificate[]" id="certificate" style="width:300px" value="'+v.med_sbj_list+'">';
});
$("#input_container").html(inputs);
```

Comment: WoW! This answer my question! Thank you!